# What the best way to build a dictionary (word count) for NLP in matlab?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, nlp

I have a frequency count dictionary,  I want to be able to read the frequency count to a given word in my dictonary.

for example 
my input word is 'about' ,so the output will be the count of 'about' in my dictionary, which 139 to be able to calculate the probability.

```
  139 about
  133 according
  163 accusing
  244 actually
  567 afternoon
  175 again
  156 ah
  167 a-ha
  165 ahh
```

I tried do this with fopen method, but not getting the wanted result.

```
1 fid = fopen('dictionary.txt');
2 words = textscan(fid, '%s');
3 fclose(fid);
4 words = words{1};
```

I tried this as well, but getting different result,

```
countfunction = @(word) nnz(strcmp(word, words));
count = cellfun(countfunction, words);
tally = [words num2cell(count)];
sortrows(tally, 2);
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: '139' 
   'about '
    '133'
    'according'
    '163'
    'accusing'  I'm getting the same dictionary as output

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're running countfunction for each instance of each word in the dictionary, rather than each unique word in the dictionary.

Here's how to incrementally improve your code:

```
words = {'hi' 'hi' 'the' 'hi' 'the' 'a'};
unique_words = unique(words(:));
countfunction = @(word) nnz(strcmp(word, words));
count = cellfun(countfunction, unique_words);
tally = [unique_words, num2cell(count)];
disp(sortrows(tally, 2));
    'a'      [1]
    'the'    [2]
    'hi'     [3]
```

However, I'd recommend using grpstats instead:

```
words = {'hi' 'hi' 'the' 'hi' 'the' 'a'};
[unique_words, count] = grpstats(ones(size(words)), words(:), {'gname', 'numel'});
tally = [unique_words, num2cell(count)];
disp(sortrows(tally, 2));
    'a'      [1]
    'the'    [2]
    'hi'     [3]
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help, its working great with all the word in the dictionary, and it take long time to run, and display all the word.
my objective is just to count only the 'input' word in the dictionary. for example the input word is 'about', the output will be how many 'about' in the my dictionary.  Input word -->  'about' the output --->  'about' [139].

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what data structure your input words come in? For example, if you have a string input_word, then the count of word in words is just sum(strcmp(input_word, words))